# Tag synonyms: config, configuration and configure

Tags: discussion

I believe [config](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/config) and [configure](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/configure) should be merged into [configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/configuration).

Answer (score 2):

I would say that all those tags are all [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (configuration of what?) and are not actually useful. That said, there are over a thousand questions tagged with it and even 19 followers (really?), so maybe they're here to stay...

Comment: We can always ask community/devs to delete tags attached to large numbers of questions.

Comment: I would tend to agree that these are bad tags: If any of them were the only tag on a question it would have zero meaning.  As such they should probably be fired, out of a cannon, into the sun. (Disclaimer: I've only glanced at the list of questions half-seriously, vomited in my bucket, and decided the tags were at fault. It could just as easily be the Debugging Tequila's fault...)

Answer (score 1):

I think `config` and `configuration` are the same, but `configure` could also tag a question related to the `./configure` step of C/C++ programs and has nothing to do with configuration.

Comment: A quick scan suggests you're correct but quite a lot of the questions would need to have it removed as it is also being used generically.

Comment: That could be tagged as [tag:autoconf].